# movie based on man locked in a house

Tags: story-identification

I can't remember all the details I was about 8 when I watched it. I want to say it's a 90's film. But the basis of the movie is a house full  mid age adults that are being taking care of. They're deemed mentally unstable or something. It's just like a regular house but there's locks on everything and they're not allowed in the kitchen or outside. The guy finally gets in the kitchen and there's a lock on the fridge. He gets it open and sees the expiration date on the milk and realizes the counselors been lying to him about the date. Makes it outside and it's a super cheesy apocalyptic scene. The whole point of the movie is to mess with your head. So much so I forgot the title. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you define "super cheesy apocalyptic scene",  nuclear, zombies, robots, aliens, robot aliens, nuclear zombies etc?

Comment: Are you sure it's a movie? Sounds more like it could be from some Outer Limits-type TV show.